Azure Kubernetes based cronjob completion event
We are using AKS v1.26.6. Our deployed code is .Net Core 6/7 based.
We created a cronjob and deployed in AKS. This job runs at fixed schedule in evening. All is good so far, now we need to know IF this job execution was success, i mean we need an event notification so we can further work based on that event notification.
Does this feature out of box available for AKS Cron jobs?

AKS Cron jobs don't have a built-in feature to send notifications upon completion.

AKS Cron jobs don't have a built-in feature to send notifications upon completion. However, you can set up automated notifications using Azure Monitor. Azure Monitor can monitor your AKS cluster and send alerts based on specific event patterns. You can configure alerts to trigger based on the completion of your Cron job. To set up Azure Monitor to trigger alerts based on the completion of Kubernetes CronJobs in AKS, First, ensure that Azure Monitor for containers is enabled for your AKS cluster.
To enable monitoring during AKS creation:
az aks create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myAKSCluster \
  --generate-ssh-keys \
  --enable-addons monitoring \
  --workspace-resource-id <Log-Analytics-workspace-resource-id>


To enable monitoring on an existing AKS cluster:
az aks enable-addons \
  --addons monitoring \
  --name myAKSCluster \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --workspace-resource-id <Log-Analytics-workspace-resource-id>


Deploy a CronJob
example
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure


Create KQL Query for CronJob Completion Events
KubeEvents
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where Namespace == "default" and Name contains "hello"
| where Reason == "SuccessfulCreate"
| project TimeGenerated, Name, Message

With the query ready, you can set up an alert in Azure Monitor:

Navigate to Monitor > Alerts > + New alert rule.
Select the Log Analytics workspace where your cluster’s logs are stored.
Under Condition, select Add condition. Use the custom log search and input your KQL query.
Define the alert logic (e.g., whenever the count of events is greater than 0).
Under Action Group, define how you want to be notified (email, SMS, webhook, etc.).
Set the alert details such as name, severity, and description.
Click Create alert rule.



References:

Monitor Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
Monitoring and logging data

